# How to calculate the steady state response $y_{ss}(t)$ of a LTI system given the Laplace transform $Y(s)$?

Tags: laplace-transform

I am given the Laplace transform of the output of a LTI system: $$Y(s) = \frac{1}{s((s+2)^2+1)}$$ Asked is what the steady state response $y_{ss}(t)$ would be. I think that $y_{ss}(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty} y(t)$, since after waiting infinit long, the system should be in steady state. (Right?)

I thought to use the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem):

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)=\lim_{s\to 0}sY(s)$$
This gives $$\lim_{s\to 0} sY(s)=\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{1}{(s+2)^2+1} = \frac{1}{5}.$$

This is different from $\frac{1}{10}$. When I let a computer algebra system calculate $\mathscr{L}^{-1}[Y(s)]
\bigg{|}_{t=\infty}$ I get $\frac{1}{10}$.
(I'm using wxMaxima and used `limit(ilt(1/(s*(s^2 + 2*s + 10)), s, t), t, inf);`.)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code should be `s^2+4*s+5`.

Comment: unlike transient response, which is with zero input but some states are non-zero at $t=0$, the steady state response needs a defined input.

Comment: $Y(s)$ is the output of the system, so its fine as written.

Answer (score 1):

For these calculations, it is better to give the *Wolfram Alpha* answers:

[inverse Laplace transform 1/(s*(s^2 + 4*s + 5))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?source=frontpage-immediate-access&i=inverse%20Laplace%20transform%201%2F(s*(s%5E2%20%2B%204*s%20%2B%205)))

Which gives the correct expression, consistent with the *Final Value* expression of 1/5:

$$\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{5} e^{-2 t} (2 sin(t) + cos(t))$$

This is very different from the complex (phasor) expression, which could inexplicably have a 1/10, but when evaluated it is still 1/5:

$$\frac{1}{10} i (e^{(-2 - i) t} ((2 + i) e^{2 i t} + (-2 + i)) - 2 i)$$